# No funciona usar dos eventos para la misma función en javaScript

Tags: javascript, eventos, onclick

El evento `click` funciona pero el evento `keydown` no. ¿Dónde está el error?

**Código:**

```js
const btnAgregar = document.getElementById('boton-agregar');   // id de un button ligado a un
input en donde escribo una tarea y al accionar el evento la agrega en forma de li a una ul.


btnAgregar.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
if (e.key == "Enter"){
    agregarItem();
}
});


btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', agregarItem);
```

El problema está en el evento de `keydown`. Es lo único que no funciona. El resto funciona perfecto y no encuentro el error.

También probé con `===` en lugar de `==` en ese mismo evento pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tu código (como lo has compartido) no se puede probar. Deduzco por lo que cuentas que el problema está en que intentas leer las pulsaciones de teclas de un botón, cuando lo que deseas es leer las pulsaciones de teclas del campo de texto.

Comment: PD: Escribiste "Si necesitan el HTML trato de pasarlo en una respuesta", pero no deberías redactar una respuesta para compartir más datos de la pregunta. Para ello deberías usar la opción de [editar pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/585073/edit) que está situada bajo ella. Aunque indicas que "el foro" no te deja hacerlo, la verdad es que el límite de contenido es tan alto que no entiendo por qué piensas eso.

Answer (score 3):

El problema que estás sufriendo es que intentas detectar pulsaciones de teclas en un botón, cuando lo que deseas es detectar las pulsaciones en el campo de texto sobre el que escribes.

Muestro a continuación un ejemplo de cómo deberías haberlo hecho:

```js
/* Simulamos tu función */
const agregarItem = () => console.log("Llamada");

/* El evento de pulsación de ENTER lo asociamos al campo de texto */
texto.addEventListener("keydown", (evento) => {
  if (evento.key == "Enter") {
    agregarItem();
  }
});

/* El evento de clic lo asociamos al botón */
window["boton-agregar"].addEventListener('click', agregarItem);
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="Escribe y pulsa ENTER cuando termines" />
<button id="boton-agregar">Pulsa aquí</button>
```

PD: No es necesario hacer uso de `getElementByID()` para acceder a los elementos a través de su `id`. Todos estos elementos se crean automáticamente en el ámbito global (`window`). Puedes acceder a ellos como una variable (`texto`) o como una propiedad de `window` si usaste algún carácter especial (como el operador de resta `-`) accediendo a ella con `window["boton-agregar"]`.

Comment: Precisamente las malas prácticas y no saber usar correctamente los ámbitos es lo que puede llegar a generar ese tipo de problemas. Para evitar esa situación y otras ambigüedades puedes optar por usar propiedades de `window` para acceder a los elementos por si `id` y declarar todas las variables "de uso global" con `let` o `const` para evitar que se definan en `window`. El problema es que muy pocos cursos o tutoriales explican qué es un ámbito, cómo se usan y en qué afectan al alcance de una variable, qué es exactamente `window`, etc.

Comment: Además (no me cabía en el comentario anterior), corrígeme si me equivoco (se me podría haber escapado en algún momento, no soy perfecto), pero nunca digo **no deberías usar**, si no que siempre digo que **no es necesario**.

Comment: Siempre agradezco las críticas (sobre todo si son constructivas). Creo que el que cometa ese error cometerá exactamente el mismo sobreescribiendo una variable global por una local (por ejemplo poniendo el mismo nombre a un parámetro) o acceder erróneamente a una variable de un ámbito diferente o global y no a una propiedad de la clase por no usar `this`.